# What happens if I place myself on a land pole?

Tags: astrophysics, earth

What happens if I place myself in the center of one of the Earth's poles?
Could I see how the earth revolves around me?

Comment: why not  to photograph star trails? You don't need to be at the pole to record the effect of Earth rotation.

Answer (score 0):

in a way, yes! a small pendulum oscillating with you would see a rotation of its plane with respect to the plane between you, the center of the earth and for example the position of New York. Also you would see a fixed star above you and the rest rotating around (the North Star)

Comment: The Foucault pendulum, of course, must be free to swing in any direction (a spherical pendulum, not a hinge-bound one).

Comment: yes @Whit3rd, the experiment of a pendulum in the North Pole is commonly used in general relativity to be able to think about the effect of mass on curvature and movement, inertia and all that.